# Dropdownlist is not updating using Yii

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii

I'm using

> PHP language , yii-1.1.13 framework and  MySQL DB.

In my Views , I have this code:

Views Code of Main Page

```
/** Start Widget **/
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
        'id'=>'dialog',
        'options' => array(
                'title' => 'Locations Management',
                'autoOpen' => false,
                'modal' => true,
                'resizable' => false,
                'dialogClass' => 'managelocation-dialog-class',
                'show'=>array(
                        'effect'=>'drop',
                        'duration'=>500,
                ),
                'hide'=>array(
                        'effect'=>'drop',
                        'duration'=>500,
                ),
        ),

    ));


    /**
     * Render dialog view.
     */
    echo $this->renderPartial('manageLocationDialog', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'locationInfo' => $locationInfo,
    ));


    $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');


    /**
     * Filter Dialog widget
     */
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
            'id'=>'filter-dialog',
            'options' => array(
                    'title' => 'Filter',
                    'autoOpen' => false,
                    'modal' => true,
                    'resizable' => false,
                    'width' => 350,
                    'dialogClass' => 'location-dialog-class',
                    'show'=>array(
                            'effect'=>'drop',
                            'duration'=>500,
                    ),
                    'hide'=>array(
                            'effect'=>'drop',
                            'duration'=>500,
                    ),
            ),

    ));

    /**
     * Render the filter dialog view.
    */
    echo $this->renderPartial('manageLocationFilter', array(
            'filterFormloc' => $filterFormloc,
            'locationInfo' => $locationInfo,
    ));

    $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
```

Views Code of Add/Edit Dialog

```
  <div id="action-button-div" class="row">
        <?php
            echo CHtml::button('Create New', array(
                'id'=>'action-button',
                'class'=>'submit-button',
                'onclick'=>"{submitActionJs();}",
                'update' =>'#filter_province_name',
            ));
        ?>
        <?php
            echo CHtml::button('Cancel', array(
                'id'=>'cancel-button',
                'onclick'=>'{$("#dialog").dialog("close");}',
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
```

Views Code of Filter Dialog

```
<div id="dialog-contents-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="filter-mode-div">
            <?php
                echo $form->labelEx($filterFormloc, 'filter_mode', array(
                    'label' => 'Filter Mode',
                ));
            ?>
            <div>
            <?php
                echo $form->radioButtonList($filterFormloc, 'filter_mode', array(
                    1=>'ON',2=>'OFF'),array('id'=>'filter_mode'
                ));
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="reset-button-div">
            <?php
                echo CHtml::button('Reset Settings', array(
                    'id'=>'reset-button',
                    'onclick'=>'{$(this.form).find("textarea, :text, select").val("").end().find(":checked").prop("checked", false);$("#ManageLocationFilterForm_filter_mode_1").attr("checked",true);}',
                ));
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="under-container">

        <div class="row">
            <div id="province_name">
                <?php
                    echo $form->labelEx($filterFormloc, 'province_name', array(
                        'label' => 'Province *',
                    ));
                ?>

                <div>
                <?php
                    echo $form->dropDownList($filterFormloc, 'province_name',
                        $locationInfo->getAllProvincesForSelection(true, 'Select Province'),
                        array(
                            'id' => 'filter_province_name',
                            'class' => 'selectbox',
                        )
                    );
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div id="action-button-div" class="row">
        <?php
            echo CHtml::button('Apply Filter Settings', array(
                'id'=>'action-button_2',
                'onclick'=>"{submitFilterActionJs();}"
            ));
        ?>
        <?php
            echo CHtml::button('Cancel', array(
                'id'=>'cancel-button_2',
                'onclick'=>'{$("#filter-dialog").dialog("close");}',
            ));
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

In my controller, below is my code:

public function actionRegisterLocation() {

```
    $model = new ManageLocationForm;
    if (isset($_POST['ManageLocationForm']))
    {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['ManageLocationForm'];

        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            if ($model->hasErrors())
            {
                $errors = '';
                foreach ($model->getErrors() as $e) $errors .= implode($e).'<br>';
                echo CJSON::encode(array(
                        'status'=>'failure',
                        'messages'=>$errors
                ));
            }
            else
            {
                $locationInfo = new LocationInfo;
                if ($model->operation_mode === AdminGeneralHelper::OPERATION_MODE_UPDATE)
                {
                    $locationInfo=LocationInfo::model()->findByPk($model->location_id);
                }
                $locationInfo->short_name = $model->short_name;
                $locationInfo->town_name = $model->town_name;
                $locationInfo->province_name = $model->province_name;

                $locationInfo->save();

                if ($model->operation_mode === AdminGeneralHelper::OPERATION_MODE_CREATION)
                    $_message = 'Create operation completed.';
                if ($model->operation_mode === AdminGeneralHelper::OPERATION_MODE_UPDATE)
                    $_message = 'Update operation completed.';


                if ($locationInfo->hasErrors())
                {
                    $errors = '';
                    foreach ($locationInfo->getErrors() as $e) $errors .= implode($e).'<br>';
                    echo CJSON::encode(array(
                            'status'=>'failure',
                            'messages'=>$errors
                    ));
                }
                echo CJSON::encode(array(
                        'status' => 'success',
                        'messages' => $_message,
                ));
            }
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "FALSE";
    }
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Below is the scenario:

1. I open the dialog for Adding a location. (Parameters are short_name, town, and province)
2. Location was Successfully added in the Grid View and DB.
3. I open the dialog for filter. It can only filter by Province.
4. When I take a look at the Dropdown lists, Location that was successfully added is not on the lists.

My question is how to update the dropdown lists of filter dialog after I successfully added a location from Add/Edit Dialog. Alternative solution is I need to refresh the browser then open the filter dialog. But it is not that user friendly. Its really a bug.

Comment: Help us help you by narrowing down the problem and remove unnecessary files or lines of code?

Comment: Hi @topher! Good day! I removed the unnecessary lines of code. Please help me to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @topher! Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @Ram G Athreya. Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: a. What is `$_message` that is returned by your register controller? You can check using firebug or browser developer tools. b. We need to see the view for the filters.

Comment: hi @topher! Please see updated code in my controller and I also added the views code of filter dialog. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update` or `replace` requires the response for the query to be html (see the source for [`CHtml::ajax()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L1253) for more detail). Your query returns `json`. You have several options:

1. You can change the controller to return all the options for the dropdown as html and continue using `update`.
2. You can change the controller to return the full dropdown as html and use `replace` instead of `update`.
3. You can change controller to return the id and value of the newly added location and use a custom javascript function to add this option to the dropdown.

Comment: Hi @topher! may you give me a sample code of option no.1 which is You can change the controller to return all the options for the dropdown as html and continue using update.

Comment: @fedel1234 stack overflow isn't a give me the code site. We'll give you solutions but you'll have to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Option No.3 and its working.

Below is the working code from my Javascript file.

```
    function submitActionJs() {
    var fareCat = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var newFareCat = toTitleCase(fareCat);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'registerFareCategory',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: $('form').serializeArray(),
        timeout: 10000,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#dialog-msg').html('Processing...');
        },
        success: function(data){
            var res = eval('(' + data + ')');
            $('#dialog-msg').html(res.messages);
            if (res.status == 'success'){
                $("#message-label").html(res.messages);
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update('fare-category-grid');
                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                window.parent.$('#filter_name').append('<option value = "' + newFareCat +  '">' + newFareCat  + '</option>');
                //sort fare category dropdownlist from filter dialog
                $("#filter_name").html($('#filter_name option').sort(function(x, y) {
                     return $(x).text().toUpperCase() < $(y).text().toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1;
                }));
                $("#filter_name").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
                e.preventDefault();
            } 

        },
        error: function(){
            $('#dialog-msg').html('Ajax Communication Error.');
        }
    }
    );

}
```

Thanks @topher for your suggestion.